# What's use of inheritedChannel() method in System class

Tags: java

Found this method in **System** class. Just curious to know about it-

```
public static Channel inheritedChannel() throws IOException {
     return SelectorProvider.provider().inheritedChannel();
}
```

[Java Doc description is :](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#inheritedChannel%28%29)

> *Returns the channel inherited from the entity that created this Java virtual machine. This method returns the channel obtained by invoking
>   the inheritedChannel method of the system-wide default
>   SelectorProvider object.*

Comment: Remarkably, if you click on the links in the javadoc you copied and pasted, they lead to more information.

Comment: yeah..i have read that. but didn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Then you don't have any need to use it. If you had the need you would recognize it.

Comment: I think it would be more constructive to answer the question instead of questioning my intention...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It’s designed for Java programs to be started on demand from `inetd` or `xinetd` on Unixy systems. Oracle has some more documentation and example code, unfortunately related to RMI, in their [Designing Services to be Launched from `inetd`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/inetd/launch-service.html) article, and there’s a very simple example in the Jetty source for [`InheritedChannelConnector`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-7.1.0.v20100505/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/nio/InheritedChannelConnector.java) and some interesting discussions in bug [JETTY-496](http://web.archive.org/web/20150517000856/http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-496?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&showAll=true) where the Jetty feature was introduced.

Answer (score 4):

From [SelectorProvider.inheritedChannel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/spi/SelectorProvider.html#inheritedChannel%28%29):

Returns the channel inherited from the entity that created this
Java virtual machine.

On many operating systems a process, such as a Java virtual
machine, can be started in a manner that allows the process to
inherit a channel from the entity that created the process. The
manner in which this is done is system dependent, as are the
possible entities to which the channel may be connected. **For example,
on UNIX systems, the Internet services daemon (*inetd*) is used to 
start programs to service requests when a request arrives on an 
associated network port. In this example, the process that is started, 
inherits a channel representing a network socket.**

In cases where the inherited channel represents a network socket
then the java.nio.channels.Channel type returned 
by this method is determined as follows:

- If the inherited channel represents a stream-oriented connected
   socket then a java.nio.channels.SocketChannel is
   returned. The socket channel is, at least initially, in blocking
   mode, bound to a socket address, and connected to a peer.
- If the inherited channel represents a stream-oriented listening
   socket then a java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel is returned. The server-socket channel is, at 
   least initially, in blocking mode, and bound to a socket address.
- If the inherited channel is a datagram-oriented socket 
   then a java.nio.channels.DatagramChannel is    
   returned. The datagram channel is, at least initially, in blocking
   mode, and bound to a socket address.

In addition to the network-oriented channels described, this method
may return other kinds of channels in the future.

The first invocation of this method creates the channel that is 
returned. Subsequent invocations of this method return the same 
channel.